# ArrayList index is always 0 (zero)

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a problem with ArrayLists in Java.
The problem is that when i add an element to the list (pointStorer), the **index doesn't increment and every time it resets and remains zero**.
Here's my code (well it's only the important part of the code):

```
private ArrayList pointStorer = new ArrayList();
private Point pointValues = new Point();

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    pointValues.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    mousePointX = pointValues.x;
    mousePointY = pointValues.y;

    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

        pointStorer.add(pointValues);

        System.out.println("Index point "+pointStorer.indexOf(pointValues));


}
```

I use the method .indexOf to know what's the index of the element that i've just added, but it remains always zero.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have only a single Point instance, do you create it only once and then assign values to it multiple times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only have one `Point` instance which you keep adding to the ArrayList, so all the indices of the ArrayList contain the same `Point`.

To add a new `Point` each time the mouse is clicked, you should create a new `Point` instance :

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    Point pointValues = new Point();
    pointValues.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    mousePointX = pointValues.x;
    mousePointY = pointValues.y;

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Ahh you're right! It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should  instantiate your `pointStorer` variable inside your `paint()` method